# How to fix PyCharm not showing "add existing" Conda Environment?

Tags: pycharm, conda

I'm using PyCharm and am attempting to add a conda environment. I was able to do this successfully a few days ago; however, when I go to add another conda environment, whether in a new project or otherwise, I do not have the option to add an existing one like I once did. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I just encountered this issue with PyCharm  2022.2.3 (Apple Silicon). Downgrading to an earlier PyCharm version (I picked 2021.3.3) solved the problem for me.